# How to set switch to on in android list view?

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview

Getting nullpointer exception while setting the switch on.

The XML definition

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >



    <Switch

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"

        android:onClick="onStatusChange"
        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
        android:textOff="Present"
        android:textOn="Absent"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the function used to initiate adapter

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Student_List.this, studentList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_NAME, TAG_ROLL, TAG_ID}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.roll, R.id.ID});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the function I use to set it checked. (Here's where the null pointer exception occurs)

```
RelativeLayout r1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.list1);
                    Switch sw = (Switch)r1.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
                    sw.setChecked(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to be able to use a custom layout for each of your list item you need to create your own adapter and set the layout of item within that adapter.

You can follow [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) to get started on creating your own custom adapter.